# Read a file of length n in logn time

Tags: file, time-complexity, read-write

Doing any(*read*/*write*) operations on the **FILE** in *any* programming language, the exact location of the file should be navigated and then it should be handled with *read*/*write* mode. Consider a file of **N** lines size, which requires a loop to read each line resulting the loop repeating for **N** times. And the complexity in reading the file turns out to be **O(N)**.

Is there any algorithm to read the file of 'N' lines in **log(N)** time.?

Answer (score 0):

It definitely depends on filesystem capabilities; for example, in FAT32 filesystem, the numbers of disk sectors which form the file are stored as a linked list, so it would require linear time (albeit with a rather small constant) to even arrive at the end of a file.

Other than that, it depends on whether we know the lengths of the lines in advance. Otherwise, it is unlikely to be possible in the general case: each position in the file which we don't read can either contain a line break or not contain it.

On the other hand, if, for example, all lines have the same length known in advance, and the filesystem allows accessing an arbitrary position in the file in sublinear time, the whole problem is solvable in that sublinear time, too.

Comment: the solution provided seems to be working. But in general scenario where developer is not aware of the file system architecture and the arbitrary positions, is there a generic method to solve this.?

Comment: @Dinesh No. If there is a sublinear solution, look at any position we don't read, and imagine two inputs: one with a newline there and the other with regular characters there. Any single answer we found can't be right for both of these inputs simultaneously.